# prove that:$m=\{1,2,3,\cdots,\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\}$

Tags: combinatorics

Determine whether there exist $n $ distinct lines in the plane having exactly m distinct points of intersection,then

$m=\{0，1,2,3,\cdots,\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\}$

This problem from IMO shortlist 1985 number 7:http://www.aoshoo.com/i/shortlist/198/1985.asp

Comment: this is incorrect , 0 is also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum possible value of m is reached when each point of intersection is distinct. If they are distinct, n lines intersect in $\binom {n}{2}$  points. So, $m\in\{0,1,2,3.....,\binom{n}{2}\}$